# For in app subscriptions and auto renewal of subscriptions through Google Play payment, does app needs to be installed through Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-install-apk, app-distribution

We are a content platform and looking to distribute our app outside of Google Play store. But for in-app purchases/subscriptions on Android does the app have to be distributed via Google Play only? If not, then what is the way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, your app needs to be published on Google Play to work with in-app billing.

> You can implement In-app Billing only in applications that you publish through Google Play. To complete in-app purchase requests, the Google Play app must be able to access the Google Play server over the network.

For more [information](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html#api).